# SOLVED! Multiplication in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, class

Is it possible to multiply this values, something like this:  Qty__c * NRPrice__c in the query below

```
PODetails2 = [SELECT  Qty__c, NRPrice__c  FROM o_Bundle__c  ];
```

or I have to do it in the VF page in order to add the Total value, if so HOW?

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!PODetails2}" var="b" >
    <apex:column  headerValue="Qty" value="{!b.Qty__c}" />
    <apex:column  headerValue="Rate" value="{!b.Bundle_Item__r.NRPrice__c}" />
    <apex:column  headerValue="Total" value="MULTIPLY VALUES" />    
</apex:dataTable>
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Here is the solution by AmatorVitae:

Comment: Hi - I see you've changed the title to include "Solved" it would be good if you can accept the answer? This will help others with the same issue :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing the multiplication in the VF Page.  Anything in between `{!` and `}` **is** a formula.

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!PODetails2}" var="b" >
    <apex:column  headerValue="Qty" value="{!b.Qty__c}" />
    <apex:column  headerValue="Rate" value="{!b.Bundle_Item__r.NRPrice__c}" />
    <apex:column  headerValue="Total" value="{!b.Qty__c*b.Bundle_Item__r.NRPrice__c}" />    
</apex:dataTable>
```

**EDIT** - This above approach does **not** work.  See below for the solution

---

Here's a recap of the conversation in the comments:

You are setting `PODetails2` via the SOQL query:

```
PODetails2 = [SELECT Bundle_Item__c, 
                     Qty__c, 
                     Bundle_Item__r.WarehouseCode__c, 
                     Bundle_Item__r.Product_Name__c, 
                     Bundle_Item__r.NRPrice__c 
              FROM o_Bundle__c 
              WHERE Bundle__c IN:contractIDs ];
```

So, in your VF page, create the `pageBlockTable` as follows.  The trick is to do the multiplication between `apex:column` tags.  Apex will display almost **anything** between `apex:column` tags, but if in stead you put the value in the `value` tag, then Apex does some special coding in choosing how to display the value (as a number? or as a hyperlink in case of a `Name` field or Lookup Field?, etc.)  So the solution is to hot-wire `apex:column` by using the first approach.

Inside `{!` and `}`, Apex process the information as a formula returning text.  So what you can do is wrap the formula inside an `apex:output` tag, and then use the tag to do the formatting.

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!PODetails2}" var="x">
        <apex:column headerValue="Quantity" value="{!x.Qty__c}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="Rate" value="{!x.Bundle_Item__r.NRPrice__c}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="Total">
            <apex:outputText value="{0, number,$###,###,##0.00}">
                <apex:param value="{!x.Qty__c*x.Bundle_Item__r.NRPrice__c}" />
            </apex:outputText>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

PS I used a `pageBlockTable` instead of a `dataTable`.  The only difference is the `pageBlockTable` has some nice styling attached to it.

Comment: I got this error message: Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '*'. Expected Number, received Object. I don't know why because Qty and NRPrice are mumber fields. Any Ideas?

Comment: can we cast both as numbers?  i'm checking the function list.  i tested the code, and it worked on my end.

Comment: Thank you for your time, i really appreciate it... I am so new in apex. How would you cast these values in the VF page?

Comment: try checking your controller to make sure the parameters are what you think they are.  Also, try making a new VF page with a StandardController on the sOjbect you're using, and test out a simple example.  Example:  <apex:page standardController="Paycheck__c">
    <apex:outputText value="{!Paycheck__c.Hours__c*Paycheck__c.TotalBenefit__c+Paycheck__c.Pay_Run__r.CKcount__c}"/>

Comment: For casting, you can only cast a string to decimal via VALUE and anything to a string via TEXT.  Concerning the error code "Expected Number, received Object", that means that one of the two parameters (either b.Qty__c or b.Bundle_Item__r.NRPrice__c) is an Object not a "field" of an object -- which is what we're looking for in this example

Comment: I will do so... I'll let you know the outcome..Thank you!

Comment: It is so weird because i checked the fields and they are "Number", so I don't know why they are showing as objects. This is how I am getting the data in the class:  public List<o_Bundle__c> PODetails2 {get; set;}  String[] contractIDs = new string[values.size()];
       
        for (integer i=0; i<values.size(); i++)
        {
           contractIDs[i] = values[i].ProductId__c ;
       }
        
  PODetails2 = [SELECT Bundle_Item__c, Qty__c, Bundle_Item__r.WarehouseCode__c, Bundle_Item__r.Product_Name__c, Bundle_Item__r.NRPrice__c  FROM o_Bundle__c WHERE Bundle__c  IN:contractIDs  ];

Comment: I figured it out.  check out my solution

Comment: hi AmatorVitae, Thank you so much, I truly appreciate your help and the time you spent. You just made my day!!! As a mentioned before, I am very new in apex and I found it I little difficult while writing classes and triggers, would you please recommend me some resources that can help me in my learning process. Also can I bother you in the future if I have some questions? Have a great day!!!

Comment: the best suggestion I can give is to keep using Salesforce Stack Exchange :)  I started developing on SF 2 years ago, and I learned everything I know from forums (mostly this site, the SF Dev Forums, and StackOverflow has some good posts too).  If you're ever stuck, just google your problem, and mostly likely the question's been asked before.  Feel free to contact me anytime =]

Comment: thanks!.. I have another problem this is more difficult, I will open another question forum. Please review it

Answer (score 10):

You can't do it in SOQL, but you can create a formula field on the object that can be queried. In all likelihood, if you need the calculation here, you'll need it somewhere else such as a report. By making a formula field, you can ensure everyone is using the same calculation.

Comment: If I can't do it by code, I will use the formula field. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

Best Idea in this case should be creating wrapper class to manage all calculations and make displaying easier

For example

```
class wrapper{

   Integer reult;
   o_Bundle__c object;

   public void wrapper(o_Bundle__c b){
      reult = /** some operations **/
      object = b;
   }
}
```

thanks to that you will have access to object and calculated values

Answer (score 1):

Use a Wrapper class then.  Have the table iterate over a list of the wrapper instead.

```
public class MyWrapper
{
  public o_Bundle__c bundle{get; set;}

  public MyWrapper(o_Bundle__c bundle)
  {
    this.bundle = bundle;
  }

  public Integer getMult()
  {
    return bundle.Qty__c * bundle.Bundle_Item__r.NRPrice__c;
  }
}
```

Comment: That will be the ideal fix, but we are trying to remove fields, so I am not allow to add more fields because the system is running too slow. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Carlos This doesn't add any fields...

Comment: hi dphil, now that i am more familiar with wrapper classes I went back to this question and i realized that your solution is correct too. Thanks!